# How would you parameterize Dagster pipelines to run same solids with multiple different configurations/assets?

Tags: python, dagster

Let's say I create a Dagster pipeline with the following solids:

1. Execute SQL query from file and get results
2. Write results to a table

I want to do this for say 10 different tables in parallel. Each table requiring a different SQL query.
What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach is to use a solid factory. `run_query_solid_factory` and `write_results_solid_factory` are solid factories that take inputs (such as name and the query or table) and return a solid that can run in the pipeline. `summary_report` waits for all the upstream solids to complete before printing out summary info.

```
def run_query_solid_factory(name, query):
    @solid(name=name)
    def _run_query(context):
        context.log.info(query)
        return 'result'

    return _run_query

def write_results_solid_factory(name, table):
    @solid(name=name)
    def _write_results(context, query_result):
        context.log.info(table)
        context.log.info(query_result)
        return 'success'

    return _write_results

@solid
def summary_report(context, statuses):
    context.log.info(' '.join(statuses))

@pipeline
def pipeline():
    solid_output_handles = []
    queries = [('table', 'query'), ('table2', 'query2')]
    for table, query in queries:
        get_data = run_query_solid_factory('run_query_{}'.format(query), query)
        write_results = write_results_solid_factory('write_results_to_table_{}'.format(table), table)
        solid_output_handles.append(write_results(get_data()))

    summary_report(solid_output_handles)
```

[image: Dag structure]
[image: Dag execution logs]

Previous Answer:

I would recommend creating a [composite_solid](https://docs.dagster.io/docs/apidocs/solids#dagster.composite_solid) that consists of a solid that handles (1) and a solid that handles (2). Then, you can [alias](https://docs.dagster.io/docs/tutorial/advanced) the composite_solid once for each of the 10 tables, which will let you pass in the SQL query via config (see [tutorial](https://docs.dagster.io/docs/tutorial/advanced))

Comment: Do you have any *answer code*? please let the others benefit from your answer.

Comment: @dboy you can find it in the official docs 
https://docs.dagster.io/docs/tutorial/advanced#reusable-solids

Comment: @BinhPham link expired.

Comment: Is there a way to have the created ops run in sequence? As in to not overload the source?

Comment: seems like api might have changed a bit since original answer - i have exact same question today - anyone know of any examples or pointers?